# Create Java object that implements an interface from Matlab

Tags: java, class, matlab, interface

For some reason, I am not able to create a Java object that implements a user-defined interface.

I tried creating a Java object that implements a pre-defined interface and it worked fine.

My interface:

```
public interface Speak 
{
    public void sayHello();
}
```

My Class:

```
public class myPerson 
implements Speak
{
    public myPerson(String arg_firstName, int arg_age)
    {
        firstName = arg_firstName;
        age = arg_age;
    }

    public String firstName;
    public int age;

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

For my class to work in eclipse, I had to export my interface as a .jar file, then I added it to the project libraries - and it worked just fine.

My Matlab file:

```
clc
clear

javaclasspath('/path/to/Speak.jar');
javaclasspath('/path/to/myPerson.jar');

driver_1 = myPerson('Bob', 39);
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Undefined function or variable 'myPerson'.
```

If I remove the `implements` interface, I can create the object just fine.

Comment: I don't know Matlab but I know Java. myParson is not an object, it's a class type. So in Matlab, you might have to declare an object or variable of type myPerson. The compiler seems to hint that.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid, I actually just tried aioobe's answer and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
javaclasspath({'/path/to/Speak.jar', '/path/to/myPerson.jar'});
```

(You need both `Speak.jar` and `myPerson.jar` on the classpath to instantiate a `myPerson`.)